# Using Python Variable in HTML / .format()

Tags: python, html, variables, string.format

I am having a really hard time getting the "marker" to show up. I do not know how to use `.format()` correctly to show the marker inside the string.

Does the variable need to be in a specific location in the string? Trying to get a grasp of this for the first time. Sorry if I am asking basic questions.

Keep getting : `""".format(marker) KeyError: 'font-family'`. Not sure where the problem is.

```
marker = "AUniqueMarker"    


# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "This is a test message.\nText and html."
html = """\
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<link rel=File-List href="Law_files/filelist.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>

# (...)

-->
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
    mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
    mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
    mso-para-margin:0in;
    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:10.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;}
</style>
<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026"/>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
  <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/>
 </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>

{marker}
</body>

</html> 
 """.format(marker=marker)
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):  If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the presence of other curly braces (`{` and `}`) in the string, otherwise the string will be misinterpreted by `format`.

You have to repeat the characters to escape them. In the string you are calling `format` on, change the line

```
{mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
```

to

```
{{mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
```

and similarly for the closing bracket.

Comment: Thank you so much. It did the trick. Had to escape all braces in the HTML. Thank you for the speedy response. Thought it was going to take a week to get anything back!

Answer (score 1):

You must double the `{` and `}` in your string, otherwise `format` will try to interpret text between braces.

<del>You can use replace to do that :</del>

```
html = """\
your html code
""".replace("{", "{{").replace("}", "}}").format(marker=marker)
```

EDIT : `replace` will transform `{marker}` into `{{marker}}`, so it will not be interpreted by `format`...

Comment: Thank you, the main idea was there and it helped solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manipulate the HTML code and add extra {} or %, python's **Template** string might be exactly what you’re looking for. Let’s take a look at an example:

```
from string import Template

t = Template('<body> $marker </body>')
t.substitute(marker='Hello World!')
'<body> Hello World! </body>'
```